How to Prevent Chrome from giving my organization access to my private data when using sync?
I have a work PC running Windows 11.
I want to use Chrome both for work and private usage, for that I use two different profiles.
When I try to login in Chrome and use its sync feature for my private account, I get the message:

Your organization will manage this profile
This account is managed by ORGANIZATION
You're adding a managed profile to this browser. Your administrator
has control over the profile and can access its data. Bookmarks,
history, passwords, and other settings can be synced to your account
and managed by your administrator

I don't want my organization to have access to my private history and passwords. (I trust the work PC enough to log myself in my private account.)
How can I use Chrome without giving my organization control over my private data?

Short answer, you cannot. Workaround, use a different browser for work vs private. Vivaldi also has a cloud sync feature, but cannot be managed by your work. Give it a try, its highly customizable, and is based on chrome. Many features that come in chrome have been implemented by vivaldi a long time ago.

“How can I use Chrome without giving my organization control over my private data?” - You cannot Chrome is on the system is managed by a group policy which will be applied to all Chrome user profiles. Using Vivaldi should only be done if approved by your system Administrator. Using unapproved and unauthorized browsers would get employees at my employer immediately fired.
